# Representing a path as a coloured image

Tags: python, numpy

Unsure what the below function does, could someone explain? The algorithm takes a path that is found by a breadth first search algorithm and returning it to the colour_path function that is meant to colour it in to show graphically on matplotlib.

Path function that I am unsure about:

```
def color_path(maze, path): #Function to represent the path when the user asks for a solution
    for (x, y) in path: #
        maze.board[x][y] = constants.RED

    if len(path):
        maze.board[path[0][0], path[0][1]] = constants.BLUE
        maze.board[path[-1][0], path[-1][1]] = constants.BLUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need to understand the data structures used:
`path` is an numpy array of shape `(path_length, 2)` and contains a list of `x` and `y` positions (pixels in the image).

- `path[0]` gives you the `first node` of the path
- `path[-1]` the `last node`.
- `path[i][0]` gives you the the `x` coordinate of a `node i`
- `path[i][1]` gives you the the `y` coordinate of a `node i`.

`board` is a numpy array with shape `(rows, columns)` and contains all pixels of the maze.

The first loop visits every `(x, y)` pair of the path and sets the color to red for these pixels:

```py
for (x, y) in path: #
    maze.board[x][y] = constants.RED

# Example path around a 3x3 square
path = np.array([[1, 1],  # right
                 [2, 1],
                 [3, 1],  # up
                 [3, 2],
                 [3, 3],  # left
                 [2, 3],
                 [1, 3],  # down
                 [1, 2],
                 [1, 1]])  # back at the start

 # (1,3) <-- (3, 3)
 #   |         |
 #   |         |
 # (1,1) --> (3, 1)
```

The last two lines of the function set the color of the start and the goal node to blue.

```py
maze.board[path[0][0], path[0][1]] = constants.BLUE
maze.board[path[-1][0], path[-1][1]] = constants.BLUE
```

Afterwards `board` is used to draw the image with walls being black, the path red, and start and goal blue.